# Запятая перед союзом

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая?
"Доказывай важность своих субъективных переживаний, и твои потуги будут осмеяны".

А также объясните правило постановки запятых перед союзом.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя теоретически здесь возможны **оба варианта (запятая и тире)**, более предпочтительным мне кажется **вариант с запятой.**

**(1) Доказывай важность своих субъективных переживАний, и твои потуги будут осмеяны.**

Аналог предложения: Ты доказываешь важность своих субъективных переживАний, и твои потуги будут осмеяны. Это ССП **неоднородного состава**, формально союз И является показателем сочинительной связи, но отношения между предикативными частями могут быть различными, в том числе причинно-следственными, например: **"Всё живое смылось с Садовой, и спасти Ивана Савельича было некому".**

(2) ДокАзывай важность своих субъективных переживАний - и твои потуги будут осмеяны.

При постановке тире  подчеркивается деление предложения на две части, **ударение на первом слове,** но тогда смысл становится другим. Ведь автор **предостерегает нас от такой ситуации**, а при постановке тире как бы предлагает **поучаствовать в ней** (доказывай - и тогда будешь осмеян).

**Примечание**

В Правилах Лопатина указывается на возможность постановки тире в определенных случаях (резкий переход, противопоставление), но для ССП тире не является основным знаком, как для БСП.

Comment: _Sibylla: тире как бы предлагает поучаствовать в ней (доказывай - и тогда будешь осмеян)._ === Нет, не так.  У автора, на мой взгляд, как раз предостережение: _**Если будешь доказывать  —  будешь осмеян**_.  Или Вы и в этом предложении предпочтёте запятую?

Comment: Если будешь докАзывать — будешь осмеян. Здесь ставится тире на месте пропуска второй части двойного союза (в этом месте делается пауза). В нашем же случае, как мне кажется, для понимания смысла важна форма повелительного наклонения глагола - нам как бы предлагается именно доказывать.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Доказывай важность своих субъективных переживаний, и твои потуги будут осмеяны.***

Лучше, на мой взгляд, здесь смотрелось бы тире:

***Доказывай важность своих субъективных переживаний — и твои потуги будут осмеяны.***

См. [***"Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник":***](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=133#pp133)

> **§ 114.** Между частями сложносочиненного предложения ставится тире,
>   если вторая часть предложения заключает в себе значение результата,
>   следствия…
>
> ***Положишь палочку на воду — и она поплывет по течению.***

Comment: Оно не просто "лучше бы смотрелось", оно здесь обязательно.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна, это сложносочиненное предложение. В ССП перед союзом обычно ставится запятая.

Запятыми разделяются предикативные части сложносочиненного предложения (простые предложения), между которыми стоят союзы:

1) соединительные союзы [и, да (в значении и), ни…ни]:

> Песок блестит на солнце тёплым, жёлтым блеском, **и** на его бархате прозрачные здания подобны тонким вышивкам из белого шёлка (М. Г.);

См:[Розенталь. Д.Э.Справочник по русскому языку: орфография и пунктуация](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=132#pp132)

Comment: Здесь тире нужно. Первая часть - следствие, вторая - причина. Тот редкий случай, когда тире не является опциональным, но обязательным.

Comment: Запятая и тире факультативны в нашем примере.

Comment: Не могу согласиться. Тире обязательно.

Comment: Ваши примеры - на другую тему. Поэтому и возникают большие сомнения, что Вы вообще поняли вопрос.